# Position of roots of a polynomial after the coefficients perturbation

Tags: polynomials, roots

Problem: Given two polynomials of equal degree:

\begin{equation}
p_1(x)=x^n+a_1x^{n-1}+a_2x^{n-2}+\cdots+a_0,\\
p_2(x)=x^n+(a_1+\epsilon)x^{n-1}+a_2x^{n-2}+\cdots+a_0.
\end{equation}

where $\epsilon\geq0.$

What are conditions on $\epsilon$ and $a_i's$, such that roots of $p_2(x)$ located to the left of roots $p_1(x)$? My aim is to move roots of $p_1(x)$ slightly to the left using the $\epsilon$. For example, if roots of $p_1(x)$ are $-2$ and $4$, I want the roots of $p_2(x)$ to be $-2.1$ and $3.8$.

My attempt:

1) Lets first consider case when $n=1$, then condition is $\epsilon>0$.

2) Now let $n=2$. Then roots of $p_1(x)$ are $\frac{-a_1-\sqrt{a_1^2-4a_2}}{2}$ and $\frac{-a_1+\sqrt{a_1^2-4a_2}}{2}$,

$\qquad\qquad$ while roots of $p_2(x)$ are $\frac{-a_1-\epsilon-\sqrt{a_1^2+2a_1\epsilon+\epsilon^2-4a_2}}{2}$ and $\frac{-a_1-\epsilon+\sqrt{a_1^2+2a_1\epsilon+\epsilon^2-4a_2}}{2}$.

We want the difference of first roots to be positive and difference of second roots to be positive as well, i.e. simultaneously satisfy the following two inequalities:

\begin{equation}
\epsilon+\sqrt{a_1^2+2a_1\epsilon+\epsilon^2-4a_2}-\sqrt{a_1^2-4a_2}>0, \qquad\qquad\qquad (1)\\
\epsilon-\sqrt{a_1^2+2a_1\epsilon+\epsilon^2-4a_2}+\sqrt{a_1^2-4a_2}>0. \qquad\qquad\qquad (2)
\end{equation}

In $(1)$ and $(2)$ I assume that square root parts are not complex. Then after some calculation, I found that conditions are $a_1<0$, $a_2<0$ and $\epsilon>\sqrt{a_1^2-4a_2}$.

Is it possible to generalize to larger degrees? Is there any intuition on geometry of roots when small perturbations are made to $a_1$ or equal amount of small perturbations are made to all $a_i's$?